# How to extract parameters and values from filename in python and assign those values to those parameters?

Tags: python, csv

I have a file name  "Aphi_AirClad_H410RW855_PulleyCurved_Lc5_G100_W550_Mode1.csv"  and I have to extract values and assign them in this way:-

```
H = 410
RW = 855
Lc = 5
G = 100
W = 510

for file in ZipFile('DeviceData.zip').namelist():
    re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z0-9]+",file)
```

and have to create a dataframe with these parameters as columns and integers as values. Can anyone please suggest me how to do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
splits = "Aphi_AirClad_H410RW855_PulleyCurved_Lc5_G100_W550_Mode1.csv".split("_")

item_prefix = ["H", "Lc", "G", "W"]
param_dict = {}

for prefix in item_prefix:
    for item in splits:
        if item.startswith(prefix):
            if prefix == "H":
                h_split = item.split("RW")
                second_split = h_split[0].split("H")
                param_dict.update({"RW": h_split[1], "H": second_split[1]})
            else:
                param_dict.update({prefix: item.split(prefix)[1] })
param_dict                                                                                                                                                                                                              
{'RW': '855', 'H': '410', 'Lc': '5', 'G': '100', 'W': '550'}
```